# JNI C++ -> Java bitmap header info and bytes to jbytearray

Tags: java, c++, bitmap, java-native-interface, jbytearray

I'm using JNI to pass an image from C++ to Java, im trying to send the bytes in a **jbyteArray** over to Java in **byte[]**. However I'm getting an error which has most likely have to do something with the size of the bytes being send.

I have tried `int len = dwBmpSize` which have the same value but the jvm keeps crashing.

What is the correct amount of bytes to initialize the jbyteArray with?

Comment: 1)  You didn't check if `GlobalAlloc` failed.  2) You should take the `min` of what you allocated and `bi.biSizeImge` and use that value to initialize and copy the bytes in to the jbyteArray.